# connect infopath 2010 to sharepoint standard server 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, infopath

We just got a license for InfoPath 2010 and we could not connect it to our sharepoint site. The following error is being displayed :

[image: InfoPath error]

Also, the server that we're using is the standard version. Is it possible to connect infopath to this type of server? What are the steps that we need to do to make this work?

Thanks in advance!